# vue-router doesn't render child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router

I am trying to push dynamic child route by `$router.push({ name: 'Warning', params: { id: warning.id }`. But when I press the button that push route - route changes correctly, but component is not rendered and I still see the parent component

That route:

```
    {
      path: '/warnings',
      name: 'Warnings',
      component: Warnings,
      children: [
      {
      path: ':id',
      name: 'Warning',
      component: FullWarning
      }
```

Comment: Do you have a new `<router-view>` in your child component (`FullWarning`)? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes

Comment: @BennettDams, thanks, it works!